# How to fix the CID set of a font?

Tags: fonts, fontforge

I have extracted [this font](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/6bbqoj2xq9tbh31md2eru/AlbanyWTJ.ttf?rlkey=w40c0m1h31cfkg7p2xsjv0gl3&dl=0) from a PDF, upon compliance with this PDF/A3 it says the the CID set of the font is incomplete. How can I see for which characters the CID set is incomplete?

I have tried using fontforge to identify where the incompleteness is and would get much from that. If anyone could explain how to identify missing CIDset it would be really helpful.

Comment: @KJ you are right, I am trying to achieve something similar to Factur-x format (PDF/A3) but it is not for Factur-x. Need to someone get the PDF complied with PDF/A3, was successful for all the PDFs but for the specific PDF using this font I am not able to comply with PDF/A3.